# How to change root directory of cmd window by default using batch file

Tags: cmd

I want to create a batch file which on double click opens cmd window with a particular directory set as root i.e when the cmd is opened the root should be D:/Studies and not C:/users/

Answer (score 0):

Type this in cmd

```
copy con 1.bat
cmd /K "cd D:/Studies"
(press F6)
```

now when you press the link , it will open the cmd at the specified dir.